# Initializing an array of lists in C#

Tags: c#, oop, collections

I trying to figure out how to use lists, arrays and collections in classes/object. I am trying to to use a array with 3 lists as a small memory bank. This is where I am at right now, the StartUp was just a desperation function hehe.

```
namespace MemoryController
{
    public class MemController
    {
        public int MemSlot { get; set; }
        public List <String>[] EnteredDigits { get; set; }
        public string MyOperator { get; set; }
        public MemController()

        
        {
          MemSlot = 0;
          List<string>[] EnteredDigits = new List<String>[3];

            EnteredDigits[0] = new List<string>();
            EnteredDigits[1] = new List<string>();
            EnteredDigits[2] = new List<string>();

            StartUp();
        }

       public void StartUp()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < EnteredDigits.Length; i++)
            {
                EnteredDigits[i] = new List<string>();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this with `Enumerable.Range`, projecting initialised `List<T>` to an *array*

```
var enteredDigits = Enumerable.Range(0, 3)
                              .Select(x => new List<string>())
                              .ToArray();
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.Range(Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.8)

> Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

[Enumerable.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates an array from a `IEnumerable<T>.`

Comment: Thanks I am still unsure how to use this, it's a linq query I know but if I use it in the constructor I have to declare a Enumerable somewhere. I have no idea how I would do that. Plus I have a few days on this already, I might just be trying something that's the complicated I don't know.

Comment: Just noticed the link updates, much appreciated will go read those and give it another shot.

Comment: @GreatGaja You don't have to declare anything, it returns a `List<String>[3]`, however ill annotate it a bit more

Comment: I was being a big dummy and did not include Linq in that class, that was the error. Big noobie mistake, your notations were clear for me :)

Comment: @GreatGaja It produces an array, just like you wanted... however if you want a list just call `.ToList()` instead of `.ToArray()`. That will give you the `Add` Method

Comment: Thanks, I removed the question because it was also returning null for some reason, just need to read more into this I am missing something obvious, great tips though. Also I wanted to create an array of 3 lists of possible, might have not been clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an initializer like this:

```cs
var enteredDigits = new List<string>[] 
{
    new List<string>(),
    new List<string>(),
    new List<string>()
};
```

Comment: Appreciated, I was looking for a way to do it without writing all of them.